# How to transpose 3D matrix (') in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose

I have a 3D matrix which its size is `185x145x3`. I want implement matrix transpose in MATLAB which denotes by `'` (Not (.')) for the 3D matrix. With 2D matrix such as `185x145`. It done by

```
X_trans=X';
```

I tried with

```
X_3D_trans=permute(X,[2,1,3]);
```

But above code is for `.'` operator, while I am looking for `'` .Could you suggest to me the way to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: The operator `'` in MATLAB is called [**complex conjugate transpose**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). I believe you would've easily found the answer, had you looked for the right thing...

Comment: Thank Dev-iL for your word. Do you think the ans of Lee correct?

Comment: @user8264 yes, if you are looking for the complex conjugate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X_3D_trans=permute(conj(X),[2,1,3]);`